# Firebase Emulators HUB UI not loading in browser

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I recently upgraded Firebase Emulators so i can use the new auth functionalities, everything works fine, after running `firebase emulators:start` it shows me the following logs in the console:

```
firebase emulators:start

i  emulators: Starting emulators: auth, functions, firestore, hosting
!  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: database, pubsub
+  functions: Using node@12 from host.
i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: dist/firetest
+  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000
i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log
i  functions: Watching "C:\wamp64\www\WasteMart\firetest\functions" for Cloud Functions...

┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔  All emulators ready! It is now safe to connect your app. │
│ i  View Emulator UI at http://localhost:4000                │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌────────────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ Emulator       │ Host:Port      │ View in Emulator UI             │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Authentication │ localhost:9099 │ http://localhost:4000/auth      │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Functions      │ localhost:5001 │ http://localhost:4000/functions │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Firestore      │ localhost:8080 │ http://localhost:4000/firestore │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Hosting        │ localhost:5000 │ n/a                             │
└────────────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
  Emulator Hub running at localhost:4400
  Other reserved ports: 4500
```

but when I open the emulator hub at `http://localhost:4000/` nothing loads up.

I opened the DevTools in Chrome and it shows these two console errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not parse content for http://localhost:4000/static/js/10.e545a6ce.chunk.js.map: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

Im not sure what is wrong or what should I try to fix this, I try to find a way of uninstall the emulators and re-install them but i had no luck.

Comment: If the emulators aren't working the way you expect, you should file an issue on the project GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Answer (score 0):

Its working now!  , I just updated firebase-tools from 9.01 to 9.10 and it downloaded emulator files ui-v1.4.1

If the error persists remove firebase-tools and install them again